# Incorrect class displayed by erb

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have the following code:

```
<% event_class = "eventInfo individual")%>
<div class=<%= raw event_class %>>
```

In this case, I expect the rendered `html` to be

```
<div class="eventInfo individual">
```

but I'm getting

```
<div class="eventInfo" individual="">
```

How do I fix this?

Edit: I got the HTML I wanted by writing:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, nil, class: event_class) %>
```

I will still leave this question up in case anyone wants to tackle the original problem though.  This looks like a bug in Rails to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug, but rather expected behaviour since you did not put the erb tag in quotation marks.
Everything in <% %> tags will be ruby-interpreted server side, so what you end up with in your html is

```
<div class=eventInfo individual></div>
```

This would be faulty html, but modern browsers have a lot of tolerance and will translate this into

```
<div class="eventInfo" individual="">
```

Just put "" around your erb tag and you are fine

```
<div class="<%= raw_event_info %>"></div>
```

EDIT: Your solution is better in every aspect, since you don't mix erb with html. I just wanted to explain what was happening originaly ;)